# Where can I ask about defragmenting?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange website can I ask about defragmentation of a PC?

Answer (score 7):

Questions about defragmentation can be on-topic on SuperUser; they even have a [defragment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/defragment) tag. With over 200 questions, your answer might already be among them. If not, please check their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) before posting your question.

Answer (score 7):

You can ask that Question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

From their [Help Page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about:
>
> 1. computer hardware,
> 2. computer software, or
> 3. personal and home computer networking
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!